# Float value not working as intended unless I add f after the initialization or initialize the variable as double

Tags: c++, c

When I compile and run the following code, x only gets printed when I initialize `float x=1.5`. It does not work for other values, for example, when I initialize `float x=1.2` and write `when(x==1.2)`, it does not print the value of x.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float x=1.5;
    while (x==1.5)
    {
        printf("\n%f",x);
        x-=1;
    }
}
```

However, when I initialize `float x=1.2f` and write `when(x==1.2f)`, the code runs as intended.

Also, if I declare and initialize x as `double x=1.2`, and write `printf("\n%lf",x);`, the code runs as intended.

This happens in both C and C++.

Comment: That sounds normal. A float converted to a double is probably not going to compare exactly equal to a number that started out as a double.

Comment: This problem will occur for all numbers that cannot be stored exactly in a `float` variable.

Comment: Try `if (x == 1.2f)`. Unlike `1.5`, `1.2` is not representable exactly in binary, so floats and doubles approximate it with different precision. By doing `x == 1.2` you're comparing a less precise float with a more precise double.

Comment: @Shawn: A `float` converted to a `double` does not change value. The `float` values are a subset of the `double` values. A `double` value converted to `float` may be changed.

Answer (score 0):

It tells the computer that this is a floating point number. If there is no `f` after the number, it is considered a double or an integer (depending on if there is a decimal or not).

```
3.0f -- float
3.0  -- double
3   --  integer
```

Comment: That is basically true, but does not explain why the issue happens. Also there is already a dublicate that explains it in great detail.